# Aggregating by two different columns

Tags: python, sql, pandas

I'm trying to aggregate this using python pandas,
I'm trying to find the Sum of spend and visitors for each network, but only aggregregate them if the months are the same

for example

| month | network | spend | visitors |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 9 | CNBC | 10 | 2 |
| 10 | BBC | 10 | 1 |
| 9 | BBC | 10 | 2 |
| 10 | CNBC | 10 | 2 |
| 10 | CNBC | 10 | 2 |

should result

| month | network | spend | visitors |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 9 | CNBC | 10 | 2 |
| 9 | BBC | 10 | 2 |
| 10 | CNBC | 20 | 4 |
| 10 | BBC | 10 | 1 |

how would I be able to do this?

Comment: what about df.groupby(['month','network']).sum()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can group your pandas dataframe by **network** and by **month** and then call the `sum` method.

```
df.groupby(['network', 'month']).sum()
```

Returns:

```
network     month       spend   visitors
BBC            9           10          2
BBC           10           10          1
CNBC           9           10          2
CNBC          10           20          4
```